# Use ChromeDriver while Chrome is running

Tags: selenium-webdriver

In the following, I am using Selenium with Python on Windows 10 (Git-Bash, not WSL) to interact with ChromeDriver.

I am currently on Chrome version 114.0.5735.110 with ChromeDriver 114.0.5735.90. Previously, I believe I was on a slightly older version of Chrome (probably still 114.0.5735.something) with I believe ChromeDriver 114.0.5735.16. On the older setup, I used to be able to keep Chrome open on my Default profile while simultaneously running ChromeDriver (also on that same Default profile). Since upgrading both, however, I get a long traceback whose most relevant part seems to be:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

The exact same code still works as long as Chrome is closed before running ChromeDriver. The issue only comes up when Chrome is open. It doesn't seem to matter what profile Chrome is using -- I've tried both using a different profile than the one ChromeDriver uses as well as the same profile (neither works).

I've googled around quite a bit and referenced past Stack Overflow answers, but none of the existing solutions seems to work. Any ideas on what I can do? I would really like to keep Chrome open while using ChromeDriver.

For reference, my code looks like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.binary_location = r"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chrome_options.add_argument(r"--user-data-dir=C:\Users\Issa\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data")
chrome_options.add_argument(r'--profile-directory=Profile 1')
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless=new')

# disable bar that says "chrome is being controlled by automated software"
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches",["enable-automation"])

driver_service = Service(r'C:\Users\Issa\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=driver_service, options=chrome_options)

driver.get("https://example.com")

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Since last update i have the same issue.
Tried to re install chrome, updated the chromedriver, downgraded chrome to the last working.
Nothing worked for me.
I agree that all the past solutions are not working also.
switched to edge until is solved.

Comment: Thank you for confirming! I'm feeling less insane :)